# Gnuplot density mapping

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

I have a set of points with x and y coordinates. I would like to plot the density of points in a particular region with the output being something like a heat map. Is it possible using gnuplot?

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use `dgrid3d` together with the `kdensity` keyword; see `help dgrid3d`.

Answer (score 1):

This may be not the best solution, but here is what I used to do.

I hope you have data file `data.dat`, which have data entry like

```
x       y       z
1.486   1.528   779666
1.487   1.528   673036
1.488   1.528   565025
.       .       .
.       .       .
```

Now plot using the following command.

```
set hidden3d
set dgrid3d 50,50 qnorm 2
set view map
splot 'data_file' u 1:2:3 palette pt 5 ps 1.5
```

Set point size `ps` whichever meets your data's demand.